# Delimiters - How to remove last 3 text items

Tags: text, applescript, delimiter

### AppleScript delimiters

#### How do I remove the last 3 text items?

My list is as follows:

```
{"Water", "Management", "in", "Ancient", "Greek", "Cities", "Jun", "1993", "pdf"}
```

I would like to remove the last 3 text item (e.g.: `"Jun, "1993", and "pdf"`).

Here is my script so far:

```
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ["USA."]
set stringToUse to "04.Oxford.University.Press.USA.Water.Mngt.in.Ancient.Greek.Cities.Jun.1993.pdf" as string
set stringUSA to last text item of stringToUse
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ["."]
set pathNames to text item of stringUSA
return pathNames
```

As a general rule it's important that:

1. The number of text items in the list can be a variable
2. The text items to be deleted are always the last three

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "USA."
set stringToUse to "04.Oxford.University.Press.USA.Water.Mngt.in.Ancient.Greek.Cities.Jun.1993.pdf" as string
set stringUSA to last text item of stringToUse
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "."
set pathNames to text items 1 thru -4 of stringUSA
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {""}
return pathNames
```